# Having issues loading second Jquery ajax request into div. Is it possible to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm pulling my hair out over here. I'm a little bit of a noob at this. Can someone point out what I a doing wrong? So I have a main page pulling in content to a div that I have positioned on a page like so:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".contentDiv").load(".MainContentContainer.html");
        });
```

Then in in the "MainContentContainer.html" I am trying to pull in content the same way but on click like so:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".button1").click(function() {
            $(".contentContainer" ).load( "pages/page1.html" );
        });

        });
```

So this works also but I can not get it to load the content in the "contentContainer" div I have specified. What happens is the content is loaded at 0 position at the top left of the screen. Is this something that you can't do or am I doing it the wrong way? Any help would be MUCH appreciated. I would have put this in Codepen but I wasn't sure if you could load external data there and show the example here.

Comment: `.load(".MainContentContainer.html");` Are you sure about that filename?

Comment: Is `.button1` in the first dynamically loaded content?  If so, you can't put an event handler on it until after it's loaded unless you use delegated event handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad, I was just looking at my code and I had position: fixed; on elements being brought into the file. I thought that would fix them within the html file I was importing but thats now how it works. It fixed them to the html file I was importing to. That will be handy to know in future projects.